# Mongo database query operation question on dates as string

Tags: mongodb

Let’s say some external component inserts data into my mongo database with Field called “startDate”. They store the value as string in mongo db in format yyyymmdd-HHmmss.

Can I still run the date time queries to fetch documents between two dates ?

Will below work as expected for above scenario?

db.test.find({ startDate:{$gt: “20201121”, $lte: “20210121”}})

Comment: it will work fine i think, because you keep the order of significant digits and are always on the left, for example if you had something like   yyyyddmm-HHmmss you would have problem, also you keep always the same number of digits for example 01 not 1, so you will be fine i think. But in general we save dates on database, and we get the string from date in any way we want it using the `$dateToString`

Comment: Storing date values as string is a design flaw, you should never do this. You may review your insert process and convert values directly into proper `Date` objects.

Comment: At this point I will not be able to change the field to date since the application is owned by other team. I am using them to fetch data’s. I am like creating a wrapper graphql api to perform crud operations on that collection.

Comment: @Takis - It is working fine for all my test cases till now. Still I wanted to be sure if am not dng it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it will but not for the same end date. It'd be better to add a day to cater for trailing zeros.

```
//data
[
  {
    startDate: "20210101-010101"
  },
  {
    startDate: "20210121-000000"
  },
  {
    startDate: "20210121-010000"
  }
]

// query 1 - not successful maybe

[
  {
    startDate: "20210101-010101"
  },
  {
    startDate: "20210121-000000"
  },
  {
    startDate: "20210121-010000"
  }
]

//query 2, successful
db.collection.find({
  startDate: {
    $gt: "20201121",
    $lt: "20210122"
  }
})
```

Comment: Sure Thanks yes all the counterparts follow the same format I mentioned in question. Only prblm is the field is string and I cannot change it at this point of time as it owned by different team.